# How can I implement Qt's Basic Graphics Layouts Example with PyQt without Multiple Inheritance

Tags: qt, pyqt, multiple-inheritance

There is a [Basic Graphics Layouts Example](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/graphicsview-basicgraphicslayouts.html) in Qt's documents. It is a good start point for my PyQt project.

But,

> The LayoutItem class is a subclass of QGraphicsLayoutItem and QGraphicsItem.

I got the error when I implementing it with PyQt.

> TypeError: could not convert 'TextLayoutItem' to 'QGraphicsLayoutItem'

I know I can not use multiple inheritance in PyQt. Does it means it is impossible to implement with PyQt?